# Getting chrome specific error in textarea inside foreign object of svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

```css
.container {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background: #EEE; /* highlight container */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="test" width="1000px" height="1000px">
    <foreignObject id="foriegnObject1" class="foriegnObject" x="960.99150848388672" y="46.62721633911133" width="40" height="30">
      <textarea id="textarea1" class="textarea" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns"></textarea>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/w30mavjo/1/)

In this case I have a container div which is of size 2000px and the svg of size 1000px and i have a textarea at the position of `x="960.99150848388672" y="46.62721633911133" width="40" height="30"`

Whenever i start typing in it the page gets scrolled automatically. 
This occurs only in the latest version of chrome.**Chrome Version  *57.0.2987***.

***OS:Apple Mac Book OS X,
Chrome Version: 57.0.2987***

How to resolve this?

Comment: checked your jsFiddle with same Chrome Version 57.0.2987 but it works perfectly.

Comment: @PranavPatel are you using the latest version of  57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)?

Comment: yes it's working in my chrome "57.0.2987.110"

Comment: In My Apple Mac, the page gets scrolled automatically as soon as i start typing in the textarea.

Comment: Chrome 56.0.2924 at Mac OS, nothing happens while typing.

Comment: @br3t Yes in previous version it works smooth, But in the current version i.e in chrome version 57.0.2987 the page gets scrolled. If you update the chrome you can see the change in the behaviour.